# Trigger a macro based on a certain value in a cell

Tags: vba

I have a macro that triggered by a button and then colours a certrain range. So like:

```
Sub colourRange()
   #Colour range
end sub
```

This all works but thing is that i have to push a button for it to work. What I am actually looking is some kind of if / else statement that triggers a macro when you fill in a certain value in a cell.

Can anbybody tell me if there is a way to trigger a macro by typing a certain value in a cell?

Answer (score 2):

Your first (natural) choice should be conditional formatting. If it doesnt work for your specific case, you can intercept the `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, myRange) Is Nothing And myRange.Value = ACertainValue Then
        Call colourRange
    End If
End Sub
```

Put the above handler in the code module of the Worksheet that you want to monitor.

Answer (score 1):

from

> triggers a macro when you fill in a certain value in a cell

I'd say that you'd want to react to *any cell* changing provided it has a been entered a *certain value*

then I'd code in the relevant worksheet code pane what follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.count>1 And Target.Value = "your certain value" Then colourRange
End Sub
```

If you want that to happen for every worksheet, then code it in ThisWorkbook code pane as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 And Target.Value = "your certain value" Then colourRange
End Sub
```